# Quadratic froms over the rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms, p-adic-number-theory

I don't understand section b, $f$ is a quadratic form over the rationals, and there is an injection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and the $p-$adic field $\mathbb{Q}_v$. I haven't understand here what the quadratic form $f_v$ is, and why its discriminant is the image of $d(f)$ under the given function in the photo.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If $q$ is given by $q(x)=a_1x_1^2 +\cdots a_nx_n^2$  for $x\in \mathbb{Q}^n$, then $q_v$ is given by $q_v(x)=a_1x_1^2 +\cdots a_nx_n^2$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}_v^n$.

$d_v(q)$ is, by definition, $a_1\cdots a_n=d(q)$ but viewed as an element of $\mathbb{Q}_v^*/(\mathbb{Q}_v^*)^2$, so indeed it's the image of $d(q)$ under $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2\to \mathbb{Q}_v^*/(\mathbb{Q}_v^*)^2$ (this is NOT an injection though).

Comment: For a quadratic form $q(x) = x^\top M x,x\in K^n, M= M^\top$ we set $d(q)=\det(M)\in K/(K^*)^2$, quotienting by the squares is to obtain that $d(q) = d(q(Bx))$ for any $B\in GL_n(K)$.

Comment: @reuns that's the standard definition of the determinant, but I'm using the definition in the document the OP joined.

Comment: Because you want the determinant to be an invariant. i.e. if $q_1\sim q_2$ then $d(q_1)=d(q_2)$.

Comment: Thanks! but why it's necessary that the map between the fields would be injective?